# FastText version before most recent change

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, fasttext

I was going through old FastText code, and started to realize it doesn't work anymore and expects different parameters. When looking at the dcoumentation , it appears the documentation has been partially updated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Which it can be seen size and iter are not in the class definition shown in the docs despite being in the parameters. I was wondering if anyone knew exact version where this change has occured as it appears I've accidentally updated it to something newer.

Answer (score 1):

Most changes occurred in `gensim-4.0.0`. There are a series of notes on the changes & how to adapt your code in the project wiki page, "Migrating from Gensim 3.x to 4":

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4

In most cases small changes to the method & variable names older code is using will restore full functionality.

There have been significant fixes and optimizations to the `FastText` implementation, especially in the realm of reducing memory usage, so you probably don't want to stay on any older version (like `gensim-3.8.3`) except as a temporary quickie workaround.